# How to add a Video Material to a ModelEntity?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I use the code to add a picture texture in RealityKit and it works fine.

```
var material = SimpleMaterial()

material.baseColor = try! .texture(.load(named: "image.jpg"))
```

I try to use this code to add a video file to be a texture, but it crashes!!!

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "mp4") else {
    return
}
material.baseColor = try! .texture(.load(contentsOf: url))
```

How can I add a video file?

Answer (score 8):

#### RealityKit video material

You can use `Video Material` in RealityKit 2.0 and higher. RealityKit v1.0 doesn't support video materials. Here's a code showing you how to apply a video material:

***Approach A***

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import AVFoundation

struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        anchor.position.z += 1.0
        self.loadVideoMaterial()
        return arView
    }
    func loadVideoMaterial() {
        guard let pathToVideo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video",
                                                      ofType: "mp4")
        else { return }

        let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToVideo)
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        // 16:9 video
        let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 1.92, height: 1.08)
        let material = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: avPlayer)
        let planeModel = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])

        anchor.addChild(planeModel)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        avPlayer.volume = 0.05
        avPlayer.play()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Also, you can add RealityKit's `VideoMaterial` this way:

***Approach B***

```
// AVPLAYER and PlayerItem
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mp4")
let asset = AVAsset(url: url!)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    
// ENTITY
let mesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 1)
let material = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: avPlayer)
let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
    
// ANCHOR
let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0,0,-10])
anchor.addChild(entity)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    
// PLAYBACK
avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
avPlayer.play()
```

[image]

#### RealityKit's VideoPlayerComponent (visionOS)

In visionOS, the `VideoPlayerComponent` is another way to create a video scene (including for HEVC video with transparency).

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var player: AVPlayer?
    let screen = Entity()
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "puppets", withExtension: "mov")!
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
            screen.components[VideoPlayerComponent.self] = .init(avPlayer: player!)
            
            let anchor = AnchorEntity()
            anchor.addChild(screen)
            content.add(anchor)
            player?.play()
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image]

#### SceneKit video material

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit
import AVFoundation

struct VRViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView.pointOfView?.position.z += 0.5
        sceneView.isPlaying = true
        self.loadVideoMaterial()
        return sceneView
    }
    func loadVideoMaterial() {
        guard let pathToVideo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video",
                                                      ofType: "mp4")
        else { return }

        let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToVideo)
        let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        // 16:9 video
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = avPlayer
        let mesh = SCNPlane(width: 1.92, height: 1.08)
        mesh.materials[0] = material
        let planeModel = SCNNode(geometry: mesh)

        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(planeModel)
        
        avPlayer.volume = 0.05
        avPlayer.play()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: SCNView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VRViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a custom model in Scene, I would like to render the video material into my custom model. How can we do that? I tried getting the mesh from the entity but it didn't work. 

Vision Pro

Comment: Do you have any idea on this? @Andy Jazz

Comment: Post your question, provide the code you have written so far, and a picture of your model.

Answer (score 2):

I found the workaround, such as below code

```
self.arView = arView
let scene = SCNScene()
scnView = SCNView(frame: arView.frame)
scnView?.scene = scene
scnView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
scnView?.scene?.background.contents = UIColor.clear
```

Then add SCN camera and set camera transform from ARFrame, such as:

```
let rotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2.0, 0, 0, 1)
        let cameraTransform = simd_mul(frame.camera.transform, simd_float4x4(rotation))

let projectionMatrix = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .portrait,
                                                                         viewportSize: self.viewBounds!.size,
                                                                         zNear: 0.001,
                                                                         zFar: 10000) )
self.arCameraNode?.simdTransform = cameraTransform
self.arCameraNode?.camera?.projectionTransform = projectionMatrix
```

Finally, add your SCN video node into rootNode
However, there is a little shifting, I think you can wait for Realitykit to support video material.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but currently RealityKit does not support videos. A video is not a normal texture, it is a set of animated textures.